# sql add another searchable item

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add another field 'field2' that can also be searched and returned in the search results.

```
$extraSQL   .= ' AND a.'.$db->nameQuote('field1').' LIKE ' . $db->Quote( '%' . $search . '%' ) . ' ';
```

If I change 'field1' in above code to 'field2' then field2 does work but I am having trouble adding both to the above code.

Sure its something very simple that I am missing but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your code I'd say something like:

```
$extraSQL   .= ' AND (a.' . $db->nameQuote('field1') . ' LIKE ' . $db->Quote( '%' . $search . '%' ) . ' OR a.'.$db->nameQuote('field2').' LIKE ' . $db->Quote( '%' . $search . '%) ) ';
```

If you want either of the fields to match, or change `OR` to `AND` if you want both fields to match.

Comment: Thank you that helped. I had to change your code because I was getting a blank page but this seems to work `$extraSQL .= ' AND (a.'.$db->nameQuote('field1').' LIKE ' . $db->Quote( '%' . $search . '%' ) . ') OR (a.'.$db->nameQuote('field2').' LIKE ' . $db->Quote( '%' . $search . '%' ) . ') ';`